# How to express an appointment "has happened"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Let's say there is an appointment between John and Peter, scheduled for yesterday at 7am.

An appointment might be "cancelled", which means that it didn't happen.

But, what word(s) would you use to describe the appointment was "completed" (i.e. John and Peter met yesterday at 7am).

Is it right to say "Did the appointment took place?" or "The appointment happened"?

*Note that I'm interested in the point of view of the appointment itself, not the people involved in it.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Did the appointment took place?

No, not like this.

> Did the appointment take place?
>   Yes, it took place as scheduled.

(Did took is simply ungrammatical.)

Another option is to use "meeting"  instead of appointment.

Strictly speaking, there was an appointment *to meet*, so if the appointment does not get cancelled, the meeting will take place.

I dare say that from a purist point of view, that is certainly preferable, as the appointment itself does not take place, but whatever the appointment was *for* might or might not happen. An appointment is an agreement to meet.

So even better:

> The meeting took place as planned.

Or if the appointment got cancelled:

> That meeting never took place!

Comment: Sorry about that mistake. So, is it right to use "take place" to express what I'm looking for?

Comment: +1 for the distinction between *appointment* and *meeting*, which OP (and indeed, many people these days) are effectively treating as synonyms. Strictly speaking, an *appointment* is more like a *booking* or *reservation* - they're things which are ***made*** in advance, so there's something "not quite right" about saying that they *happen* (again?) later.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford Dictionary of English, **appointment** is

> an arrangement to meet someone at a particular time and place

So 'The appointment took place' would mean that the act of making an appointment occurred rather than the meeting took place. I certainly agree with @oerkelens about the benefit of replacing *appointment* with *meeting* in your sentence. The latter word expresses well what you intend to say while the former expresses something different and not necessarily idiomatic.

Comment: Why not *the appointment (or even better **meeting**) occurred*?

Comment: @bib *Appointment occurred* would mean that the act of making the appointment took place, according to the dictionary — not that the *meeting took place* as intended. I think there's nothing wrong with using *occurred*.